# What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site to get a definitive answer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which is the appropriate Stack Exchange site where a question can be asked that is not seeking a solution to a problem, but, instead seeks an "authorized" or canonical answer?

For example, I want to know if it is safe or OK to run Microsoft disk defragmenter on a server. I already have advice through Microsoft technet, but need a pointer to documentation or the "official" word.

Comment: Check out SE DeepThought please, but don't bother if all you get is `42` please!

Comment: What's 42 in this case, and what's the URL for this? I cannot find it.

Comment: Well there's another SE site coming up, that will give you the question for this answer. It will encorporate the whole earth as being part of it ... (Did you ever read Douglas Adams' "Hitchhikers guide to the Galaxy"?) **Don't Panic!** This was just a joke.

Comment: I didn't mean my question to  be mysterious. A consultant with no pointer to documentation, said it was unsafe to run the defragmenter. I just want to find Microsoft's writeups (if they exist) on the subject.

Comment: like [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but for programmers?

Comment: I'm just thinking about, if we could setup something like the imaginary _SE DeepThought_ site (or it's follow up _Questions for Definite Answers_) at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

> *"Which is the appropriate Stack Exchange site where a question can be asked that is not seeking a solution to a problem, but, instead seeks an "authorized" or canonical answer?"*

Well, this would 1st require you to sort out all of the *non-canonical* answers, you already have found, for your question.

Also what do you consider to be *"authorized"*? There are companies having their support to participate at SO for certain tags. Nevertheless, getting answers by these support users, doesn't make them finally *"authorized"*.

Asking for 3rd party resources is considered off-topic for most of the SO tags, and SE sites anyway.

I'm afraid there's no such SE site, we can recommend for you.

Comment: this answer is _authorized_ by me

Answer (score -1):

> What is the appropriate Stack Exchange site to get a definitive answer?

First and foremost, it depends on the question. Each site has has goals and objectives and notions of on-topic-ness and off-topic-ness. You can see the site's goals and objectives on the site's Help under ***Take the Tour...***, and you can see a discussion of on-topic-ness and off-topic-ness in the site's Help under ***"Detailed answers..."***.

I view the site's Goals and Objectives as the "coarse-grained" classification tool. It provides me with a "sniff test" and tells me if I should investigate the intersection of a question with a site further. If my question does not intersect with the site's goals and objectives - that is, it cannot pass the sniff test, then I don't investigate it further and I don't ask the question there. If the question does pass the sniff test, then I investigate further by visiting Detailed Answers section.

Some sites in the Stack Exchange network have better discussions of on-topic-ness and off-topic-ness than others. For example, take a look at this one from the [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). They try hard to provide thorough examples so there's no ambiguity or confusion.

Sometimes policy is vague and the community does not have clear direction. I've got a few questions on some Meta sites asking for policy clarification. Some of those questions have gone unanswered. The vagueness coupled with no clear direction is a failure of leadership of the site. I don't know how to help you with classifying your question in this case since leadership is not providing a required input. In this case, its probably best to fall back to Goals and Objectives, and see if the question intersects with it.

As an example of confusing policies that could benefit from clarification (or a rewording in the Help section), see [Super Users](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) Detailed Answers. First, the site claims computer software, computer hardware and home networking questions are on-topic. Then it claims electronic devices are off-topic. Computer hardware are electronic devices, software runs on electronic devices, and the switching equipment in a network is electronic devices, so one of two things happens. First, it makes all hardware questions off-topic and potentially all software and network questions off-topic. Or second, it means "electronic devices" is a useless criteria which should be ignored. I don't think published policy should be ignored (I look at it as an egregious transgression), so the site should do a better job of articulating its policies to the user of the site.

There's some hand waiving because each site has goals, objectives and notions of on-topic-ness and off-topic-ness, but the site's policies are sometimes elided by its members. That is, policy is discarded in favor of a particular user's or group of user's whims. I know this problem first hand on Stack Overflow, but I suspect other sites experience the issue to varying degrees.

**The take away**: You can usually tell what's supposed to be on-topic and off-topic by looking at the site's Goals and Objectives and Detailed Answers section. The site's policies may or may not be followed. And its not always clear what's on-topic and off-topic by looking at disposition of previous asked similar questions.

---

> Which is the appropriate Stack Exchange site where a question can be asked that is not seeking a solution to a problem, but, instead seeks an "authorized" or canonical answer?

So it looks like there are two questions here. First is the "proper site" and that was answered with the titular question above.

Second is the question of canonical answers. All sites can provide canonical answers. If you don't feel you received a canonical answer, you can start a Bounty on a question and request one.

You can usually get a reference to material support an answer in the answer itself. If you don't, then you can add a comment to an answer request a reference. Usually one will be provided because the particular subject matter expert knows exactly where to go for the reference.

If the community does not have a particular nugget of knowledge or a member who posses it (and replies), then you can't get a canonical answer even though you asked.

Sometimes it appears you have a canonical answer but you don't. For example, [there's a highly upvoted and accepted answer about Big-O notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/608639) on Stack Overflow. Its wildly popular and spectacularly wrong.

**The take away**: you can usually get a canonical answer. Sometimes you have an answer that appears canonical but its not.

---

> I want to know if it is safe or OK to run Microsoft disk defragmenter on a server.

OK, so the answer to this is: it depends.

If its a server at your house, then its most likely on-topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If its a server in the enterprise and you are in IT or an operator, then its most likely on-topic at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

If you are going to error, err on the side of [Super User](https://superuser.com/). The folks at Super User are generally friendlier and don't have the arrogant, elitists attitude that sometimes permeates at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Sometimes, you find yourself in a position where it feels like the question should be on-topic at both, but its on-topic at neither due to site rules and arbitrary application of policy.

For example, I wanted configure all the Java machines on the network at my house from a single point with a particular policy.  It was nothing clever or spectacular - I just wanted to provide a policy to all Java VM to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3. Server Fault would not take it because it was not enterprise related. Super User would not take it because they felt it was enterprise related due to the centralized administration element.

**The take away**: for this particular question it could be [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Error on the side of [Super User](https://superuser.com/).